# Get Contents from Text File and Replace Keywords PHP

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a form. I'm using "post" method that sends and emails to multiple people that registered. Then the $body of the email is based on a template. No database, no classes, simple form. Yes I read up about this already they're all there I just couldn't put it together, related to this case.

The text "email_template.txt" should have something like:

```
Hello #firstname# #lastname#. Thank you for registering! Your registered email is #email#
```

Would look like this upon processing by PHP

```
Hello **John Doe**. Thank you registering! Your registered email is **example@example.com**.
```

On my php I have something like:

```
<?php 
//form and validation
$firstname = "John"; // inputed name on the form, let say
$lastname = "Doe"; // inputed last name
$email = "example"; // inputed email 

//email message
$body = ... some type of a get_file_content....
mail($_POST['email'], 'Party Invitation', $body, 'From: admin@admin.com');
?>
```

Where $body is the email message to the registrants submitted via this PHP form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sprintf will work good

your template could be:

> Hello %s %s. Thank you for registering! Your registered email is %s
>
> $body = sprintf($fileContents,$firstname,$lastname,$email);

or `str_replace()`, pretty much a find replace.

> $body = "Hello #firstname# #lastname#. Thank you for registering! Your registered email is #email#";
>
> $body = str_replace("#firstname#",$firstname,$body);
>
> $body = str_replace("#lastname#",$lastname,$body);
>
> $body = str_replace("#email#",$email,$body);

Comment: This won't work somehow.... $body = file_get_contents(email_template.txt);
    $body = str_replace("#firstname#",$firstname,$body);
    $body = str_replace("#lastname#",$lastname,$body);
    $body = str_replace("#email#",$email,$body);